# Desativar loja WooCommerce temporariamente

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Como fazer para colocar uma loja no Wordpress feita com plugin [WooCommerce](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) em manutenção?

Pensei em tirar o menu 'LOJA' do topo do site, porém se alguém tiver o link salvo no navegador, poderia utilizar e acessar normalmente.

Pensei em desativar o plugin, mas não sei se apenas isso irá resolver e quando querer voltar a loja, se vai voltar normalmente.

Lembrando que existe um site no Wordpress e dentro dele uma loja, qual a melhor forma de tirar temporariamente do ar este loja? E depois voltar sem perder nenhuma configuração?

Comment: Acho que existe um plugin para isso. Só lembro de ouvir vagamente, mas não sei se era realmente sobre o WooCommerce.

Comment: É uma funcionalidade bem legal que está pedindo, mas assim de primeira não acho que é um problema de programação fácil de resolver ou responder. A parte automatizada do WooCommerce deve precisar de um "reverse-engineer" e tem  parte do seu Theme próprio. Pessoalmente, precisaria de uma boas horas para entender e resolver o problema, por isso voto pra fechar como "muito ampla".

Answer (score 1):

Não testei esse código mas acho que pode funcionar. Adicione ele ao arquivo functions.php do seu tema.

```
function my_woocommerce_maintenance_mode($content) {
// condição para paginas do Woo. Mais infos: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/
    if( is_woocommerce() or is_shop() or is_product_category() or is_product_tag() or is_product() or is_cart() or is_checkout() or is_account_page() ) {
   // Mostra o que vc quiser aqui.
   $content = "Em Manutenção";
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','my_woocommerce_maintenance_mode');
```

Talvez seja uma boa ideia tb esconder os produtos usando CSS caso vc tenha inserido eles em alguma página fora do woo com shortcodes por exemplo. Algo do tipo:

```
.products, .product {display: none !important;}
```

Algumas coisas que eu levaria em consideração:

1. Fazer algo para que o Google não indexe essa página "Em Manutenção". Seria chato os clientes da loja procurarem e nos resultados do Google só ter em "Manutenção". E para isso vc pode aprender mais sobre status 503  aqui: https://yoast.com/http-503-site-maintenance-seo/
2. Talvez vc queira deixar esse modo de manutenção para todo mundo menos para vc (administrador do site ou gerente) e ai basta adicionar uma condição do tipo: 
   `!current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' )`
   na função criada acima.